# Set Chrome to use desktop version of website

Tags: chrome-for-android

How can you get Chrome to always use the desktop version of websites?  I am on a Jelly Bean tablet and I can't see any reason to use the mobile versions at all.

Comment: From the menu? The checkbox that says 'Request desktop site'.

Comment: Are you asking about SO or your own website?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I think you should add that as an answer, instead of a comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a chrome-command-line file which causes chrome to load sites in desktop mode by default. The only way to stop this however, is to remove the file.
See [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1811101)

Or you could install the [Chrome UA Switcher app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appo2.ua) although this requires root access so may not be suitable if you're not rooted.