# Always use desktop mode for specific websites on Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I tap one of my favourite site, Chrome suggests me the link to mobile version, but I do not want it. I want to disable it only for my favourites.

I want to set the desktop mode only for some selected website, not for all

I use Chrome with Lollipop on Nexus 4. How can I disable this feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Chrome to use desktop version of website](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49039/set-chrome-to-use-desktop-version-of-website), but it seems impossible to do it for certain sites only.

Comment: I want to set the desktop mode only for some selected website, not for all